# ValueError: Negative dimension size caused by subtracting 12 from 1 for 'max_pooling2d_1/MaxPool' (op: 'MaxPool') with input shapes: [?,1,1,64]

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

I'm using Keras with Tensorflow as backend,nhere is my code:

```
K.clear_session()
model=Sequential()
model.add(layers.Conv2D(32,(3,3),padding='same',input_shape=(49,43,1),activation='relu'))
model.add(layers.Conv2D(64,(3,3),activation='relu'))


model.add(layers.MaxPool2D(pool_size=(8,8)))
model.add(layers.Conv2D(32,(3,3),padding='same',activation='relu'))
model.add(layers.Conv2D(64,(3,3),activation='relu'))

model.add(layers.MaxPool2D(pool_size=(8,8)))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(layers.Dense(256,activation='relu'))
model.add(layers.Dense(4,activation='softmax'))
```

Answer (score 0):

When I run your code, I get a different output - different numbers:

> ValueError: Negative dimension size caused by subtracting 8 from 3 for '{{node max_pooling2d_1/MaxPool}} = MaxPoolT=DT_FLOAT, data_format="NHWC", ksize=[1, 8, 8, 1], padding="VALID", strides=[1, 8, 8, 1]' with input shapes: [?,3,3,64].

Your input is too small to go through all the layers. I added the output of each layer on the code below. When it reaches the second MaxPool layer, it's already too small to be divided by 8.

```
model=Sequential()
model.add(layers.Conv2D(32,(3,3),padding='same',input_shape=(49,43,1),activation='relu'))
# Output: (49, 43, 32)
model.add(layers.Conv2D(64,(3,3),activation='relu'))
# Output: (47, 41, 64)

model.add(layers.MaxPool2D(pool_size=(8,8)))
# Output: (5, 5, 64))

model.add(layers.Conv2D(32,(3,3),padding='same',activation='relu'))
# Output: (5, 5, 32)
model.add(layers.Conv2D(64,(3,3),activation='relu'))
# Output: (3, 3, 64)
model.add(layers.MaxPool2D(pool_size=(8,8)))
# Output: How can I divide 3 by 8???

model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(layers.Dense(256,activation='relu'))
model.add(layers.Dense(4,activation='softmax'))
```

There are a lot of questions and blog posts about computing layers' output.

So either increases your input or remove some layers in your model.